# Loading cached remote audio files to AKPlayer on iOS, instead of using local file

Tags: swift, audio-streaming, audiokit

So far I’ve been working on a multiple audio playback project using `AKPlayers`, triggered by `AKSequencer` to obtain perfect sync, looping and advanced signal processing. It’s been going well, but now I need some insight before I jump into the next level.

I am trying to play the exact same function with remote mp3 files - streaming arrays of mp3 files from remote URL address. However, `AKPlayer` so far doesn’t seem to support streaming functionality.

One possibility I found on this website, though, is Ryan Francesconi’s answer on the thread ["How can I get AudioKit to stream an audio file from a remote URL?”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52232378/how-can-i-get-audiokit-to-stream-an-audio-file-from-a-remote-url). Here’s how he suggested:

```
guard let remote = URL(string: "https://www.sample-videos.com/audio/mp3/crowd-cheering.mp3"),

let data = NSData(contentsOf: remote) else {
AKLog("Remote failed to load.")
return
}

let cachedFile = FileManager.default.homeDirectoryForCurrentUser.appendingPathComponent(remote.lastPathComponent)
try? data.write(to: cachedFile)
let player = AKPlayer(url: cachedFile)
```

So, before I start experimenting with this, could anybody (Mr. Francesconi, ideally) inform me how to implement this code **on iOS**? Would it be safe(in terms of seamless sync and looping) to develop with this cache-and-load idea for a multiple audio file playback project? Would be extremely helpful if I can learn more about this point. Much appreciated. <3

Comment: I think it should be the same idea as long as your application has permission to save files to a temporary location.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of terminology this is not even a *cache* because cache is considered as temporary storage (and in case of iOS will be erased when the system thinks it's the best) while this approach actually saves data into the file system. In general I don't see that many risks with the idea of pre-downloading and then using downloaded files because you're working with filesystem and it's extremely fast.

The only thing I would really care for is for space being consumed by the downloaded files. You would probably need to clear your temporary files (if they're temporary) when app is inactive to avoid memory issues.

To better understand how and most importantly where your files will be stored please refer to [Apple filesystem docs.](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, inokey. Looks like I have to download the audio files onto `temp/` folder and delete them when the app goes inactive. I am still learning Swift step by step and looks like this will be another challenge. Could you kindly show me an example of basic download-and-load code, if possible? I particularly don’t understand **how to declare ‘cachedFile’** in a specific directory part. Sorry for being a newb.

Comment: For example, `FileManager.default.homeDirectoryForCurrentUser.appendingPathComponent(remote.lastPathComponent)` doesn't seem to work on iOS. Are there any alternatives?

Comment: @Gavin first you need to answer the question if the files being downloaded are really temporary files. That of course strongly depends on business logic of your app. If they're temporary you can actually default to caching mechanism using `NSCache` and again with relation to the size of the items you put in cache. If the files are not temporary meaning the app will use them as resources over and over, you can work with file manager.

Comment: It will be definitely Cache, as the target audio will be changed/updated each time. I was wondering if you could give me a short example of saving remote files with `NSCache` and loading it? Much appreciated.